# nine point smooth in OpenCV

Tags: python, image, opencv, smoothing

How can i apply nine point smooth using OpenCV?

Info : Nine point smooth will take a 3x3 square of 9 pixels each and determine the count of each pixel.The counts per pixel are then averaged, and that
value is assigned to the central pixel.

Nine Point Smooth : http://www.people.vcu.edu/~mhcrosthwait/clrs322/2DFilteringconcepts.htm

Comment: Googling "opencv 2d filtering python" suggests this: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the docs mentioned in the comments: https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d13/tutorial_py_filtering.html. It would be:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('opencv_logo.png')

blur = cv2.blur(img,(3,3))
```

Or slightly more manually:

```
kernel = np.ones((3,3), np.float32)/9
dst = cv2.filter2D(img,-1,kernel)
```